# Read background color cell on excel with IExcelDataReader | C#

Tags: c#, excel, .net-core, cell, background-color

So, my target is read the background color cells on my importex Excel file.
This is my code in C#, running .Net Core 2.2:

```
var fileName = "C:\\myfile.xlsx";

        //System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

        try
        {
            System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

            using (var stream = System.IO.File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
                {
                    do
                    {
                        while (reader.Read()) //Each ROW
                        {
                            IExcelDataReader tmp = reader;
                            // how can get the colour cell from tmp obj ?
                        }
                    } while (reader.NextResult()); // Move to NEXT SHEET

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

i need an help about color cell reading, i saw every codes into this library but i didn't find the Cell color reading.
There somone who has also used this library and can tell me how to read background color cell?

Thanks

Comment: The point of this library is to return the data in the Excel sheet, not the formatting. If you need the formatting you should probably use EPPlus or the Open XML SDK

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos for the response, i thought the same... i hoped to not changing the library..but i will do.

Comment: Looking at the repo I see you can retrieve the numeric format for a field and the [CellStyle](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader/blob/7854beef5df455dd9fa889435ca5a1274049b8bd/src/ExcelDataReader/CellStyle.cs) but that doesn't include coloring